# show content only to users that visited a certain page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say that there are two pages A and B.
The user will be on page A and for a certain  to show it needs to check if the user ip was registered on page B. This should reset every 24 hours and hide the content until the user visits the page B again.

```
This is what I have in mind:
On page A:

<div> hidden;
get user ip;
do{check page B for user ip;
    if(user ip found on page B)
      {show <div>;}
   }while(<div> is hidden);

On page B:
get user ip;
show user ip for 24 hours; (so it can be read)
```

I am a c++ noob, very new to html and java that's why I need help

Comment: Not something you can do with plain JS. You'll need a server and a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a beginner too, but I have read about PHP Sessions: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp . Maybe that could help you.. if the value of the session variables would be different every day..

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot, with it I actually made the script and it's working.